# Batch IF command that has multiple varia

Tags: batch-file

So I wanted to create a code in batch that can make both C and c valid to go to :color
This is the only way I was able to do it, but I was wondering if there is a more "efficient" way.

I'm new to coding and the programming world, so I'm not a Batch expert.

```
echo Choose again (C) or go back to Main Menu (M)?
set /p choice=Your choice: 
if %choice%==C goto :color
if %choice%==c goto :color
if %choice%==M goto :menu
if %choice%==m goto :menu
```

my idea was something like

```
if %choice%==C,c goto :color
```

or

```
if %choice%==C& c goto :color
```

I will appreciate any and all help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read `HELP IF` *... the /I switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string
compares....*

and try at the command line

```
IF /I %choice%==m @echo Menu
```

Comment: Thank you, PA. The code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @PA.'s answer, batch doesn't support implicit logical operators (AND/OR) but you can emulate them as described in: [How can I use multiple conditions in “If” in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868026/how-can-i-use-multiple-conditions-in-if-in-batch-file)

Taking a look into powershell may be a good idea if you want to go further with logical programming while keeping the familiar feel of the cmd environment.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it will certainly help me in the future, and I have got some ideas how to implement it into my current project.